# How do I detect laser line from 2 images and calculate its center using python opencv?

Tags: python, opencv

How can I detect laser line using 2 images, first with laser turned off and second with turned on and then calculate its center?
These are my images:
[img1.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efli5.jpg)
[img2.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8W7w.jpg)

This is my code:

```
import cv2
import time

img1 = cv2.imread("img1.jpg")
img2 = cv2.imread("img2.jpg")
img_org = img1
img1 = img1[:,:,2]
img2 = img2[:,:,2]

diff = cv2.absdiff(img1, img2)
diff = cv2.medianBlur(diff,5)
ret, diff = cv2.threshold(diff ,0 ,255 ,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

cv2.imwrite("output1.png", diff)

count = 0

height, width = diff.shape[:2]

start = time.time() # time start

for y in range(height):
    for x in range(width):
        if diff[y,x] == 255:
            count += 1
        elif not count == 0:
            img_org[y, round(x - count/2)] = [0, 255, 0]
            count = 0

end = time.time() # time stop
print(end - start)

cv2.imwrite("output2.png", img_org)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

This code takes red channel from both images, compare them to detect difference, then blur and treshold the difference image. This doesnt work good enought because on the top is some white that shouldn't be there. [output1.png (diff)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHwNV.png)

For detecting center of thresholded line I have tried looping through every row and pixel of the threshold image, counting white pixels. It works correcly but because of slow python loops and arrays calculating one 4032x2268 thresholded image takes about 16 seconds. For testing my code is setting laser line center to green pixels on output2.png. [output2.png (img_org)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7s0Aq.jpg)

How can I make laser detection more accurate and center of line calculation way faster?
I'm fairly new to opencv.

Comment: Not sure for your case, but you may try using Hough lines (https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghlines/py_houghlines.html) for getting line.

Comment: @SeB In my case, the laser line can be curved so I can't do it that way.

Comment: Not sure I could further help, but you may better explain what is your expectation saying 'more accurate and center of line'.

Comment: @Seb I said 'laser detection more accurate and center of line calculation way faster', because 'This doesnt work good enought because on the top is some white that shouldn't be there.' and 'It works correcly but because of slow python loops and arrays calculating one 4032x2268 thresholded image takes about 16 seconds.'

Comment: Maybe you don't need full resolution for finding the ROI, it may be worth trying to use lower resolution for finding the ROI and rescale into original image. You may try to get connected components and exclude abnormal number of pixels with abnormal shape.

Comment: well yes python loops are slow. that's why everyone uses numpy or OpenCV or any other library (from python) for the heavy lifting. if you really have to, you could play around with numba. that's a JIT for python code. -- numpy: get indices of nonzero (white) elements, then get min and max of those indices.

Comment: accuracy: no binarization. just subtract background from foreground, and then find the peak/mode (per pixel row). that ought to be giving you a good approximation of the center of the laser line. -- also make sure the picture isn't overexposed by the laser. overexposed means the red laser turns into white pixels. turn down exposure for the camera a little, until the laser doesn't appear white anymore. best would be if the room is dark, so you have no  stray light, only laser.

Comment: @Christoph Rackwitz How do I find the peak/mode per pixel row? I Have tried numpy argmax but it detects the x position of the laser very irregularly and is very inaccurate

Comment: look at the difference picture before thresholding it. don't even threshold it.

Comment: @Christoph Rackwitz I have tried without threshold and it looks very bad. https://i.imgur.com/7UvSaih.jpg

Comment: that's not a difference picture

Comment: @Christoph Rackwitz That was final picture with green pixels at laser detetcion x. This is difference picture: https://i.imgur.com/3JPMTmp.png

Comment: you see the red channel, right? you see saturation/clipping there. -- take the difference, look (with your eyes) at each color plane individually. you'll see red is completely saturated, bleeding into blue and green. *I said* you need to turn down the exposure to prevent that. if you don't, you can completely forget about the red channel because it's junk. due to this bleeding effect/defect, you could now use the blue/green channels because they likely aren't saturated, i.e. have local maxima that aren't clipped. that's bad tho, because you should fix the overexposure in the first place.

Comment: for a _proper_ subtraction of light, you'll have to remove the gamma mapping, i.e. apply a gamma of 1/2.2 = 0.45 first. _then_ you have linear values, that you can sensibly subtract from each other. the image sensor is linear, but then it compresses its values with a gamma map of roughly 2.2 (it's more complicated), and those compressed values is what everyone works with, mistakenly.

Comment: here: remove gamma to linearize, difference, take green channel (and don't reapply gamma because it doesn't matter for just looking at it): https://imgur.com/a/HYT1ULL

Comment: @Christoph Rackwitz I turned down expositions and these are new photos: https://imgur.com/a/RJpJxPi Now how do I remove gamma mapping? Once I do that, how do I detect the center of the line from this corrected difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. difference
2. gaussian blur to suppress noise, and smooth over saturated sections
3. `np.argmax` to find maximum for each row

I would also recommend

- some more reduction in exposure
- PNG instead of JPEG for real processing. JPEG saves space, okay for viewing on the web.

Gamma curves don't necessarily matter here. Just make sure the environment is darker than the laser. Exact calculation depends on what color space it is exactly, and the 2.2 exponent is a good approximation of [the actual curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB#Transformation)

```py
im0 = cv.imread("background.jpeg")
im1 = cv.imread("foreground.jpeg")
(height, width) = im0.shape[:2]

# gamma stuff, make values linear
#im0 = (im0 / np.float32(255)) ** 2.2
#im1 = (im1 / np.float32(255)) ** 2.2

diff = cv.absdiff(im1, im0)
diff = cv.GaussianBlur(diff, ksize=None, sigmaX=3.0)
plane = diff[:,:,2] # red
indices = np.argmax(plane, axis=1) # horizontally, for each row

out = diff.copy() # "drawing" 3 pixels thick
out[np.arange(height), indices-1] = (0,255,0)
out[np.arange(height), indices  ] = (0,255,0)
out[np.arange(height), indices+1] = (0,255,0)
cv.imwrite("out.jpeg", out)
```

[image: out]